# NoMethodError when there is a method

Tags: ruby

I am creating a Die class that has a function to output the number of the die. It has been named both printout and output, but the function continues to fail because of a NoMethodError. This is my code:

```
class Die

  def initialize()
    @number = rand(7)
  end

  def output()
    puts @number
  end

  def roll()
    @number = rand(7)
  end

end

Die.new.roll.output
```

Here is my error when I run the code:

> undefined method `output' for 2:Integer (NoMethodError)

Any ideas?

Comment: `Die.new.roll == 2` (or 1, 3, 4, 5, 6). `2.output` is undefined.

Comment: (1) Note that `rand(7)` might return `0`

Comment: (2) Instead of duplicating the code, you could (should) just call `roll` from within `initialize`.

Comment: (3) the empty parentheses are superfluous, just write `def initialize`, `def roll` etc.

Comment: Did you actually read the error message? What object does the error message say has no method named `output`? What does the error message say the class of that object is? What is the class you defined the method `output` in? Is that the same class as the error message says? If no, what does that tell you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must call like this:

```
die = Die.new
die.output # => 1
die.roll
die.output # => 3
```

First you need to instantiate the object (`Die.new`) into a variable (`die`).
Then call your method on it.

Note: better to use `rand(1..6)`

Without using a variable, the better you can do is:

```
Die.new.output # => 3
```

It is not possible chain methods as you did (or follow the answer by [Martin Zinovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950886/5239030))

Comment: Or implement `to_s` and call `puts Die.new` instead of having the object `puts` itself.

Comment: I agree @Stefan. Also, get rid of `output` and use `attr_reader :number` instead. Call `roll` from within `initialize`, as you already ponited out.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to chain method you should return instance in the end:

```
class Die
  def initialize
    @number = rand(7)
  end

  def output
    puts @number
  end

  def roll
    @number = rand(7)
    self # Here
  end
end

Die.new.roll.output
```

Comment: Chaining does not make much sense when hald of the methods are not chainable, IMHO.